# asp.net ajaxtoolkit autocomplete does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, autocomplete

I try to work AutoCompleteExtender but it does not work. I use ajaxToolkit and web service file. there is no error both of them. I think script can be wrong please give me suggestion for fixing.

```
< ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
                           runat="server" 
                            BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
                            ID="autoComplete1" 
                            TargetControlID="TextBox"
                            ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx" 
                            ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
                            MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
                            CompletionInterval="1000"
                            EnableCaching="true"
                            CompletionSetCount="20"
                            CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
                            CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
                            CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
                            DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
                             OnClientShowing="true" >
                                  <Animations>
                                <OnShow>
                                    <Sequence>

                                        <OpacityAction Opacity="0" />
                                        <HideAction Visible="true" />


                                        <ScriptAction Script="
                                            // Cache the size and setup the initial size
                                            var behavior = $find('AutoCompleteEx');
                                            if (!behavior._height) {
                                                var target = behavior.get_completionList();
                                                behavior._height = target.offsetHeight - 2;
                                                target.style.height = '0px';
                                            }" />


                                        <Parallel Duration=".4">
                                            <FadeIn />
                                            <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValue="0" EndValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" />
                                        </Parallel>
                                    </Sequence>
                                </OnShow>
                                <OnHide>

                                    <Parallel Duration=".4">
                                        <FadeOut />
                                        <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" EndValue="0" />
                                    </Parallel>
                                </OnHide>
                            </Animations>
                            </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**AutoComplete.asmx:**

```
 public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {


        SqlConnection cn = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["U"].ToString());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Stoc  WITH (NOLOCK) where  KeySentences like @myParameter";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myParameter", "%" + prefixText + "%");
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        //Then return List of string(txtItems) as result
        List<string> txtItems = new List<string>();
        String dbValues;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            //String From DataBase(dbValues)
            dbValues = row["KeySentences"].ToString();
            dbValues = dbValues.ToLower();
            txtItems.Add(dbValues);

        }

        return txtItems.ToArray();

    }
```

Thanks for your answers..

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors?  Are you sure you're getting any data back?  That empty "catch" block will likely be causing you to miss any errors that are happening.  Set a breakpoint and see if you are getting errors in the "catch" block, and , if not, if you are getting anything back from your database call.

Comment: Open Chrome's dev tools' **console** and look at, is there any error?

Answer (score 0):

I test with my ajaxtoolkit4.5 error on this properties.

`OnClientShowing="true"`.

Unsure what do you want to do but remove this work for me.
(I copy your code by remove database connection and work)